# Struts 2 make dynamic parameter

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, url-parameters

I am using Struts 2 and JavaScript. I want to edit a parameter value or add parameter to URL with JavaScript to make dynamic parameter. I can not set value for `param` why this not have `id`. Any other form of do?

```js
var urle = document.getElementsByName("vari");          
    urle.value = 5;
```

```jsp
<s:url var="urlex" action="actionDo"><s:param name="vari" value=""/></s:url>
```

Comment: That's good but what is your question?

Comment: edited value of param with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts tags are JSP tags that compiled and executed on server, JavaScript is executed on client browser. You can't access the server from javascript code without making ajax request. But you don't need too. Use

```
var url = '<s:url var="urlex" action="actionDo">' +'?vari=' + val;
```

Comment: with javascript can edited this <s:url var="urlex" action="actionDo"> for this <s:url var="urlex" action="actionDo"><s:param name="vari" value="5"/></s:url> ?????

Comment: @user2711590 Your solution will not work because requires unescape the ampersand and it's not dynamic parameter.

Comment: @user2711590 You could parametrize the url tag on server and parameter values *have to* take also from server via OGNL expression.

Comment: how to convert a type var of javascript to OGNL?

Comment: Noway, OGNL has nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set jsonObject when this action class has been called. So according to set parameter it will set parameter dynamic.

Comment: <s:url var="remoteurl" namespace="/discountManagement" action="displayAllDiscount">
  <s:param name="jSONObject" value="%{jSONObject}"></s:param>
 </s:url>

Comment: So it is not required to convert in OGNL.