# jqgrid edited cellurl with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, struts2

I am using struts2-jqgrid and javascript. when jqgrid load completed this get `<s:url var="updateurl" action="pagosActualizar"/>` and the jqgrid generate in view source html `options_gridtable.cellurl = "/Cuenta_Corriente_LBS/pagosActualizar.action";`, now the problem i have a var in javascript and want add a paramater to this url for example: `options_gridtable.cellurl = "/Cuenta_Corriente_LBS/pagosActualizar.action?cod=1";`. Any form of editad this line with javascript?

//JAVASCRIPT

```
$.subscribe('rowsel', function(event) {
var id = event.originalEvent.rowid;// this is the parameter for the url
var data = jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('getRowData',id);
var estado = data['estado.descripcion'];
var cod = data['correlativo'];      
if(estado === 'PENDIENTE'){
    jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('setColProp', 'fecha_acuerdo', {editable:true});
            // here cod for edited url in jqgrid
     }
   }
```

//MYJSP

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontableModificar"><s:param name="codigo"><s:property value="cuentacorriente.idcuentacorriente"/></s:param></s:url>
<s:url var="updateurl" action="pagosActualizar"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Plan de Pagos Modificar"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="false"
    gridModel="gridModel"                    
    autowidth="true"
    sortable="true"
    gridview="true"   
    cellEdit="true"  
    cellurl="%{updateurl}"
    onCellSelectTopics="rowsel"                             
>
```

//VIEW SOURCE HTML

```
options_gridtable.datatype = "json";
options_gridtable.url = "/Cuenta_Corriente_LBS/jsontableModificar.action?codigo=12";
options_gridtable.cellurl = "/Cuenta_Corriente_LBS/pagosActualizar.action";
options_gridtable.height = 'auto';
options_gridtable.pgbuttons = true;
options_gridtable.pginput = true;
options_gridtable.gridview = true;
options_gridtable.autowidth = true;
options_gridtable.caption = "Plan de Pagos Modificar";
options_gridtable.autoencode = true;
options_gridtable.cellEdit = true;
options_gridtable.oncellselecttopics = "rowsel";
```

Well the flow is he user click in cell of jqgrid, later trigger a event that get the rowid and validated the field to be edited, the problem is that when edited the cell is use the cellurl but only send the content cell to edited and not the rowid that need for update the register, i need the two the rowid and cell content.

Comment: Is this `value="cuentacorriente.idcuentacorriente"` you need? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748564/struts2-make-dynamic-parameter/18748564#18750788

Comment: i need set parameter to <s:url var="updateurl" action="pagosActualizar"/> with var id = event.originalEvent.rowid;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "beforeSubmitCell" Event. Documentation is given in following link.
[Documentation of "beforeSubmitCell"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing&s%5B%5D=cellurl)

Ex.
beforeSubmitCell:{cod:cod}.

1st cod is name of variable posted to a server
2nd cod is value of variable comes from your javascript

Answer (score 0):

that is me banned acc, i found answer:  jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{editurl:"jsontable.action?searchString="+valor}).trigger('reloadGrid');

PD: Me banned because i was new, but now i know more.